# How do I read single lines from data consisting of multiple lines in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I need to process data inside a richtextbox to output to an exact range of cells and I need to process each line of data to a single cell.

The total amount of data is 52 lines in the richtextbox and I want each data (each line) placed in a single cell range (C17:C42,H17:H42)

I've already tried it with my code:

```
range = objSheet.get_Range("C17:C42,H17:H42", Missing.Value);
range.set_Value(Missing.Value, richTextBoxReceive);
```

but I get 52 data in each cell instead, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It will work

```
string s = richTextBox1.Text;
        var k = Regex.Split(s, "\\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);

        foreach (string str in k)
        {
            //do what you want
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
```

Comment: what i have to write in curly brackets?how do i write it to each cell?

Comment: inside curly braces you get only single line values. so what you need with your single line values can be done inside curly braces. you get single line values in str variable inside curly braces.

Comment: oh i see,but i still have no idea how to handle the single line to each cell in range C17:C42,can you help me more?